# Multiselect vue.js - Trigger event if no results found

Tags: javascript, vue.js, multi-select

How can I trigger an event if no results are found when I type some text to search for an item?
Thanks!

```
      <multiselect
        v-model="value"
        :options="getSkillList"
        placeholder="Rechercher une compétence"
        :searchable="true"
        noResultsText="Aucun résultat"
        @select="addSkill"
        ref="multiselect"
        @search-change="updates"
        class="multiselect-pink"
      ></multiselect>

      <!-- Button trigger modal -->
      <button
        type="button"
        data-bs-toggle="modal"
        data-bs-target="#newSkillModal"
        class="btn btn-outline-primary w-100 ms-3"
      >
        <font-awesome-icon icon="plus-circle" class="me-2"></font-awesome-icon>
        Ajouter une nouvelle compétence
      </button>
```

I want to enable/disable the button if the user can't find what he is looking for in the search input.

eg 1: user types 'Jav' , autocompletion proposes 'Java', user is happy and select 'Java' because data is available in DB.

eg 2: user types 'JavaFX', autocompletion proposes 'No results', user is not happy, but the button becomes enabled so he can add 'JavaFX' to the DB.

Comment: Do you have some code snippets? What have you tried? There is a `search-change` event. If the result is empty then maybe then trigger an event? https://github.com/vueform/multiselect#events

Comment: I don't have code snippets. The search-change event returns the value after every key stroke. And since I type text to use the auto-completion feature, the value is never null.